# OneDrive variable in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: onedrive, sql, sqldeveloper

We are storing SQL scripts in a shared Onedrive.
Since colleagues have personal and a shared OneDrive I want to use the %OneDriveCommercial% variable.

This one works fine (I run this in Oracle SQL developer):
`@"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\TEST SHAREPOINT\ORACLE\TABEL.SQL";`

This one doesn't work:
`@"%OneDriveCommercial%TEST SHAREPOINT\ORACLE\TABEL.SQL";`

The `%OneDriveCommercial%` variable does run when I run it in the file explorer.

Comment: Provide a screenshot of your system variables showing that `%OneDriveCommercial%` is defined. If you cannot navigate to `%OneDriveCommercial%` within File Explorer, it means it's not defined.

Comment: Does the value of `%OneDriveCOmmercial%` have a `\\` (backslash) at the end of it?  Your string does not compensate for it not being there.  Just a thought.

Comment: @Ramhound: %OneDriveCommercial% is defined since it works in the file explorer. But when I run it in SQL developer it doesn't work. Providing a screenshot isn't possible due to privacy rules within the company.

Comment: @squillman: thank you for the thought. Already tried this before posting. Without luck.

Comment: You’re missing a \ in your syntax. If the variable works within File Explorer. You’ll have to use the ability to debug the script to determine what is actually being evaluated. Without extensive debugging capabilities, which I suspect won’t be allowed, I can’t help you determine what’s actually happening with the script